# Setting memory on a custom heap

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Is it possible to take a heap handle from HeapCreate() and set all available memory to a certain value?

I've tried enumerating the heap by region and setting it that way, but I get access violations.

I basically want to set the memory in my heap to a custom value that I can use for debugging, before it's ultimately destroyed via HeapDestroy.

Comment: I don't think this the good way to debug your code or to fix memory leaks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no, you can't fill the heap with a specific value".

You could wrap your heap access functions with debug versions, for example

```
// In some header file
#define HeapAlloc(a, b, c) MyHeapAlloc(a, b, c, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define HeapFree(a, b, c) MyHeapFree(a, b, c, __FILE__, __LINE__)

... 

// In a separate source file:

#ifdef HeapAlloc
#undef HeapAlloc
#undef HeapFree
#endif

struct extra
{
    extra *next;
    size_t size;
    const char *file;
    int line;
};

extra* head;

LPVOID MyHeapAlloc(HANDLE heap, DWORD flags, SIZE_T size, const char *file, int line)
{
    LPVOID res = HeapAlloc(heap, flags, size + sizeof(extra));
    if (!res)
    {
        cout << "Allocation failed, called from " << file << ":" << line << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    extra *p = reinterpret_cast<extra*>(res);
    res = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&p[1]); 

    p->next = head;
    p->size = size;
    p->file = file;
    p->line = line;

    memset(res, 0xAA, size); 
    return res;
}

BOOL MyHeapFree(HANDLE heap, DWORD flags, LPVOID mem, const char *file, int line)
{
    extra *p = reinterpret_cast<extra*>(mem);
    p = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&p[-1]); 

    extra *q = head;
    extra *prev = 0;
    while(q)
    {
        if (reinterpret_cast<void*>(&q[1]) == mem)
        {
            break;
        }
        prev = q;
        q = next;
   }
   if (!q)
   {
       cout << "Attempt to free memory that wasn't allocated from " << file << ":" << line << endl;
       return false; 
   }

   /* Unlink q - if prev = NULL then it's the first one, so just move head */
   if (prev)
   {
      prev->next = q->next;
   }
   else
   {
      head = q->next;
   }

   memset(mem, 0xBB, q->size);
   return HeapFree(heap, flags, reinterpret_cast<void *>(q); 
}
```

I have just typed all that in, so there may be minor typos, but hopefully it shows you a method of dealing with memory allocations. For some case, you may have to pad the `extra` struct to be a multiple of 16 or 32 bytes to ensure alignment of the following data. You can of course, at any time, dump the linked list pointed to by `head`, to see what is allocated.